# How to make a search function for sql database , and how to get time when info from a table was edited?

Tags: asp.net

I couldn't find :
Lets say , I have 3 textboxes on my asp.net website:

```
1.Name ___________
2.Code ___________
3.ID   ___________
```

I want to add a label near the texbox , and if someone edits the information from name or code or id , the label will turn to -> date when the info was changed there and so on .

so it should be like this lets say :

```
1.Name ________ : Info from Name was changed last time 02/20/2012 .
```

also I want to make a search function .

Comment: Please show us your effort before asking for help. What did you try? What _exactly_ are you stuck on?

Comment: well that's the problem , I've searched and couldn't find something that would help me go on , so I don't know.

Answer (score 0):

Make another coulmn in your database & update with things changed by user with date...

to search

first make that coulmn indexed (for fast search)

query will be like :

```
select * from table where Item like @search+'%'
```

or

you can use match or contain query for full text search...

remeber do not use query like

```
select * from table where Item like '%'+@search+'%'
```

Comment: how ? I need to auto update when he changed the info not manually

Answer (score 0):

on buuton click u can update or keyup event ... or after mouse lose focus on textbox