# How to determine the last time when records have been inserted, updated or deleted for a table?

Tags: asp.net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to make a search function for sql database , and how to get time when info from a table was edited?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9505032/how-to-make-a-search-function-for-sql-database-and-how-to-get-time-when-info-f)

How can I determine the last time when records have been inserted,
updated or deleted for a table ?

someone told me

```
select *
from sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats
where database_id = db_id( 'readpasttest' )
```

But I don't know how to use it  I have a database table on asp.net site where I add informations like this:

```
edit-1.Name : Jax
edit-2.Age : 24
edit-3.Code : 12515
```

so when the users edit something lets say the name Jax it will be like this

```
edit-1.Name : newName - This was edited last time : the time/day !
```

Please help ,ty

Comment: 'database table on asp.net site' is useless information. Your database could be an ODBC-linked plain text file, excel spreadsheet, or a couple old guys in a room with a teletype and a couple tin cans and a string.

Comment: Sorry for my broken english. so I have a database on localhost.and each time I edit a field near it should be a label saying the last time when I edited it.

Comment: No, this isn't about broken english. It's about not saying at all what your database is. MySQL? SQL Server? DB2? Oracle? Paradox? etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For changes, you can add a `datetime` column to the table called 'LastModified' or something like that, and write the current date/time to it every time you write a record.

Alternatively, if you need to know when a record was *deleted* you can write a trigger that intercepts inserts/updates/deletes to the table in question, and write the timestamp value to another table, along with identifying information about the affected record.

The best way is to implement 'soft deletes' where a record is marked with some kind of status value (e.g. a 'IsDeleted' column) that can be flipped and subsequently ignored by other code in the application when reading from the table.

Comment: I dun get it:D , sorry , I want to add something that auto gets the date/time when a record was changed

Comment: Right, write a trigger for the table, insert the record information into another table along with the date/time. There's no silver bullet here, there's no way to get this information from SQL Server as far as I know. Otherwise we'd all be doing it :)