# How to make a table to get the date/time when values from other tabels were edited? asp

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to make a search function for sql database , and how to get time when info from a table was edited?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9505032/how-to-make-a-search-function-for-sql-database-and-how-to-get-time-when-info-f)

I have a table with 3 columns : Name,Age,Birthday,date
Also there's a option on my asp.net website page on each line of columns an edit button so I can edit the text from name,age,birthday.
How can I make let's say when I edit the text from name column , the date column will have the Value : "Name was edited : date/time" and so on .

Would someone help me ? I've tried this since 4 days ago and I couldn't find something.
I'm using SQL database 2008,
Thanks

Comment: Why don't you create a new field called: "DT_LAST_UPDATE"? Then you create a trigger on insert/update to update this field with a getdate().

Comment: I wish if I knew how to do it !

Comment: Explain what exactly you don't know how to.

Comment: I don't understand " trigger on inster,update " and how to use getdate()

Comment: Ok, whats the name of the table?

Comment: information is the table name

Comment: Ok, give me a break and more later I write what you have to do! Okay?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, 
follow the example. (Remember, we can do this different )

*First of all, you have to add a new column to your table*

```
Alter table INFORMATION add LastUpdate datetime null
```

Then you create the Trigger (take care, you have to declare the variable Name like your table)

```
Create TRIGGER trig_Information
ON Information
FOR UPDATE 
AS 
BEGIN
    declare @Name as varchar(100) /*Look up your column type*/

    select @Name = i.Name from Inserted i

    update Information set LastUpdate = getdate() where Name = @Name 
END
```

So, everytime someone update any register of this table, the trigger will update the field LastUpdate with the date/time of the operation.

MS. If your table has more than one PK, specify at the where clause.

see ya

Comment: Oky thanks a lot so 1.I created a table called LastUpdate , datetime , null . 2.I need to declare a string to send it via sql on c# asp.net , string insert = "Create Trigger trig_information ON Information FOR Update as begin etc..." ? and then use sql command? thank you

Comment: No man, you don´t have to create a table, only a new field in your table. Then, you execute this Create trigger at Sql Server and everytime that someone update this table: Information, the field LastUpdate will be updated with the datetime.

Comment: sorry I've wanted to say table , and I execute it like I said ? string = "the trigger"; and then execute it with sql command

Comment: Yeah, on the Microsoft Sql Server Management Studio.

Comment: couldn't make it work..god I so fail

Comment: I don't know how to make it work